# Prove $\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\sqrt{\frac{a^3+a^2+1}{a^2+a+1}}\ge3$ for $abc=1$

Tags: inequality, tangent-line-method

> Let $a$, $b$, $c\ge0$, $abc=1$, prove that
> \[\sqrt{\frac{a^3+a^2+1}{a^2+a+1}}+\sqrt{\frac{b^3+b^2+1}{b^2+b+1}}+\sqrt{\frac{c^3+c^2+1}{c^2+c+1}}\ge3.\]

The following inequality fails:
\[\sqrt{\frac{a^3+a^2+1}{a^2+a+1}}\ge\frac{a+2}3,\]
because $o\left(\sqrt{\frac{a^3+a^2+1}{a^2+a+1}}\right)=o\left(\sqrt a\right)<o(a)=o\left(\frac{a+2}3\right)$.

---

The correct method(s) can be seen in the answer below.

Comment: What does the summation sign in the title have to do with anything?

Comment: It means $\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}}$, I'll make it clearer. @DavidG.Stork

Comment: This makes no sense.  What does "cyc" have to do with a term that has just a single variable ($a$)?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Now, the condition $abc=1$ indicates there are three variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

It is enough to show for positive $x$ $$\sqrt{\frac{x^3+x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}} \geqslant 1+\frac13\log(x)$$

---

Another way, we make a different estimate to avoid the need for differentiating logs etc..  Note:
$$\frac{x^3+x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}-\frac{2x+1}3 = \frac{(x-1)^2(x+2)}{3(x^2+x+1)}\geqslant 0$$
$$\implies \sqrt{\frac{x^3+x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}}\geqslant \sqrt{\frac{2x+1}3}$$
$$\implies \sum_{x\in\{a, b, c\}} \sqrt{\frac{x^3+x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}}\geqslant \sum_{x\in\{a, b, c\}}\sqrt{\frac{2x+1}3} \\ \geqslant \frac3{\sqrt3}\;\sqrt[6]{(2a+1)(2b+1)(2c+1)} \\ \geqslant \sqrt3 \;\sqrt[6]{(2+1)^3}=3$$

Where we have used AM-GM and Holder's inequalities in the last two steps...

Comment: As an aside, since OP mentioned "tangent line method", this can be considered a tangent line method that better makes use of the condition $abc = 1$.

Comment: Can you give a bit more? I don't know how to prove an inequality with logarithms like that.

Comment: @youthdoo I have given above another route which avoids proving the inequality estimate involving logs. The first step essentially remains the tangent line though! Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes. I solved it as well. $\sqrt{\frac{x^3+x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}}\ge\frac{1+2\sqrt x}3$. In this way, AM-GM is even more direct.

Comment: Yes, $\frac13(1+2\sqrt x)$ is a nice one to use - not as tight as $\sqrt{(2x+1)/3}$ but simpler for a one step AM-GM afterwards.